# Codeigniter load view in new tab

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to implement a search engine where search results should load in a new tab using code-igniter.I have a search form in my view and i need to load the results in a  new tab. Currently am loading view using $this->load->view();

Comment: Well anything client side is not related to the framework, you'd probably want an anchor with target="_blank"

Comment: Can we pass an array along with anchor tag?i need to pass search result array to view or will use sessions.

Comment: You can actually submit a form to target _blank as well : 

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/form-submission-new-window/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you want it to open in new (browser) tab: It's easiest. Just use `target="_blank"` in the form tag.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>path/to/search_result" method="post" target="_blank">
       <input type="text" name="search_term" id="search_term">
       <input type="Submit" id='Search' value="Search">
</form>
```

That's all.

More elegantly on the same page:
You need ajax for this. Here is an example for the following html:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="search_term" id="search_term">
   <input type="button" id='Search' value="Search">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Some jQuery:

```
$("#Search").click(function(){
   var dataString = $(this).parent("form").serialize();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: dataString,       
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>path/to/search_result',
        success: function (results) {
            $("#results").html(results);          
        }
   });
});
```

Your **search_result** controller could be:

```
function search_result(){
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
    //do your thing with the search term
    $this->load->view('your/view', $your_data_array);
}
```

Comment: thanks bud
but I want to open two pages at same time in new tow windows

Answer (score 2):

If you have different functions (or controllers) for creating and previewing reports, for example http://localhost/appname/test/create and http://localhost/appname/test/view, you can open new browser window when calling preview function, using like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/appname/test/view" target="_blank" >PREVIEW REPORT</a>
```

and your test will open in new window. if this is what you want.

Comment: it is not like an href link...I have a single textbox form in my view and a search button.On click search button, i need to fetch all data from database and load that array to new view in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

> **You just need to set target blank to submit button click.**

```
<form name=f1 method=post action=test5.html>

<input type=text name=name value='plus2net'>

<input type='submit' value='Open default action file test5.php' 

onclick="this.form.target='_blank';return true;">

</form>
```

This worked like charm for me! No extra code or logic needed.

[Reference from this link](https://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/submit-new.php)

Comment: Your answer has formatting problems, mixes few styles of html and doesn't add nothing new to 5 year old question, because all of that is said in previous answers and in a better way.